# How to test services declared in AndroidManifest.xml with Robolectric 2

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a service declared in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.test.app.Service" android:exported="false"/>
```

During test, when I try to get it like this - I get empty list.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, Service.class);
List<ResolveInfo> result = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(intent , 0);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. [Robolectric issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/416).